# AndroidPlot xml not rendering in Android studio

Tags: java, android, xml, androidplot

The AndroidPlot XYPlot will not render in the xml preview. I am using AndroidPlot 0.6.1. I have the jar in my libs folder. And I have it as a dependency in the Gradle script. In addition, I am able to compile, run the application, and see the graph.

It is pretty tedious though to have to run the app in order to see simple visual changes. I watched the Maven quickstart video, and I saw that the creator Nick Fellows was able to see the preview.

Here is the stacktrace from the preview:

`java.lang.AssertionError
    at android.content.res.BridgeResources.getDimension(BridgeResources.java:345)
    at com.androidplot.util.Configurator.parseFloatAttr(Configurator.java:145)
    at com.androidplot.util.Configurator.inflateParams(Configurator.java:236)
    at com.androidplot.util.Configurator.configure(Configurator.java:322)
    at com.androidplot.util.Configurator.configure(Configurator.java:286)
    at com.androidplot.Plot.loadAttrs(Plot.java:371)
    at com.androidplot.Plot.init(Plot.java:316)
    at com.androidplot.Plot.<init>(Plot.java:249)
    at com.androidplot.xy.XYPlot.<init>(XYPlot.java:150)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.createNewInstance(ViewLoader.java:413)
    at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.loadView(ViewLoader.java:105)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.LayoutlibCallback.loadView(LayoutlibCallback.java:177)
    at android.view.BridgeInflater.loadCustomView(BridgeInflater.java:214)
    at android.view.BridgeInflater.createViewFromTag(BridgeInflater.java:142)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:806)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:64)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:782)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:385)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.inflate(RenderSessionImpl.java:413)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge.createSession(Bridge.java:321)
    at com.android.ide.common.rendering.LayoutLibrary.createSession(LayoutLibrary.java:350)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask$2.compute(RenderTask.java:497)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask$2.compute(RenderTask.java:485)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runReadAction(ApplicationImpl.java:894)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.createRenderSession(RenderTask.java:485)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.render(RenderTask.java:590)
    at com.intellij.android.designer.designSurface.AndroidDesignerEditorPanel$6.run(AndroidDesignerEditorPanel.java:480)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.execute(MergingUpdateQueue.java:320)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.execute(MergingUpdateQueue.java:310)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue$2.run(MergingUpdateQueue.java:254)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.flush(MergingUpdateQueue.java:269)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.flush(MergingUpdateQueue.java:227)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.run(MergingUpdateQueue.java:217)
    at com.intellij.util.concurrency.QueueProcessor.runSafely(QueueProcessor.java:238)
    at com.intellij.util.Alarm$Request$1.run(Alarm.java:351)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)`

I have notice that whenever I remove the custom xml attributes (below), I am able to preview the graph. This means, though, that I can't style the graph the way I want through the preview.

`androidPlot.titleWidget.labelPaint.textSize="@dimen/title_font_size"
            androidPlot.graphWidget.rangeLabelPaint.textSize="@dimen/range_tick_label_font_size"
            androidPlot.legendWidget.textPaint.textSize="@dimen/legend_text_font_size"`

Upon further research, I also noticed that this only happens when the xml attribute is set equal to some other resource e.g. ="@dimen/title_font_size" or ...title="@string/test_string". The preview works fine if it was ="15sp" and "test" instead. The preview works for hard coded items. How do you get it preview with resource parameters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To start, you definitely don't want to have the jar in your libs dir while at the same time including it as a Gradlee dependency.  I'd suggest sticking with just the Gradle dependency.

As to your question, Configurator doesn't always play well with IDE previews and isn't guaranteed to work.  The good news is a new version of the library has just been released (0.9.3) which includes many new Styleable attrs, including attrs for the items you listed.  Update your dependency and then:

```
androidPlot.titleWidget.labelPaint.textSize="@dimen/title_font_size"
androidPlot.graphWidget.rangeLabelPaint.textSize="@dimen/range_tick_label_font_size"
androidPlot.legendWidget.textPaint.textSize="@dimen/legend_text_font_size"
```

becomes:

```
ap:labelTextSize="@dimen/title_font_size"
ap:rangeLabelTextSize="@dimen/range_label_font_size"
ap:legendTextSize="@dimen/legend_text_font_size"
```

Answer (score 0):

The AndroidPlot XYPlot is runing with gradle version

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.androidplot:androidplot-core:0.6.1'
}
```

add library in project

Comment: I have added the library; the jar is in my libs directory. The preview won't render.

Comment: i have use this library in gradle... it is working fine for me.. you don't use lib folder jar... try this library in gradle....